# Tables: when adding border, cells expand

Tags: html, css, html-table, spacing

I have a table of fixed width and height, and usually, it evenly distributes the cells to fit the given width and height. However, once I add borders on **only some** of the cells, the cells are no longer evenly spaced.

It appears that the cells with the border get more width than the other cells. Additionally, the cells with a thicker border get wider than the ones with a thin border.

Here is some code showing what happens. The green cells are the ones with a `border-left`, and the red and blue cells have no right or left border.

```html
<table style="width: 500px; height: 1000px; border-spacing: 0; background-color: gray;">
  <tr>
  <td style="background-color: blue; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: green; border-left: white solid 1px; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: red; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
      <td style="background-color: blue; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: green; border-left: white solid 1px; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: red; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
      <td style="background-color: blue; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: green; border-left: white solid 1px; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: red; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
  <td style="background-color: blue; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: green; border-left: white solid 1px; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: red; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
      <td style="background-color: blue; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: green; border-left: white solid 1px; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: red; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
      <td style="background-color: blue; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: green; border-left: white solid 1px; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: red; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
  <td style="background-color: blue; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: green; border-left: white solid 1px; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: red; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
      <td style="background-color: blue; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: green; border-left: white solid 1px; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: red; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
      <td style="background-color: blue; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: green; border-left: white solid 1px; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: red; border-left: none; border-top: white solid 1px;"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

In case this is a browser-specific issue, here is a screenshot of **Chrome 66** on Mac OS X High Sierra.[image: Screenshot of table]

I have confirmed in other browsers, and the same thing happens:

- Safari 11.1
- Opera 52
- Firefox 57

My question is:
**What causes this** and **how do I fix it?** Please note that in my real code, I have borders of different thicknesses.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what's causing it but I have a workaround.

Add a transparent border around all cells (use `!important`):

```
td { border: 1px solid transparent !important; }
```

then you'll also have to add `!important` to every individual cell that you add a border to.

```
<td style="background-color: green; 
    border-left: white solid 1px !important; 
    border-top: white solid 1px !important;">
</td>
```

I tried adding `box-sizing` to fix/understand what's happening but it seemed to have no effect. The overall size of the table may be affected with the added borders; you'll have to check that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I actually have borders of different thicknesses, so I can't use this hack. I'll keep looking into why this happens.

Comment: Add that to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, until i specified a with of an arbitrary 10% for all TD's

apparently this happens when no size is specified at all.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't seem to work for me. I tried it in the example above, here's what it looked like... [Result (imgur)](https://imgur.com/UPxD8l5)